# Building React usecontext in typescript got compile issue

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, react-redux, react-context

So I am trying to build a useAuth context, so after user login to app, then the jwt token can be access from any component later
I am facing a strange compile issue never had before, please see screenshot:
[image]

plain code as below:

```
    import { createContext, useContext, useReducer } from "react";
import authReducer, { initialTokenValue } from "../reducers/authReducer";

const AuthContext = createContext(initialTokenValue);

export const AuthProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(authReducer, initialTokenValue);

  const fetchNewTokenValue = (token: any) => {
    dispatch({
      type: "GET_AUTH_TOKEN",
      payload: token,
    })
  };

  const value = {
    token: state.token,
    fetchNewTokenValue,
  };


  //VS code complain AuthContext as: Cannot find namespace 'AuthContext'.ts(2503)
  //No quick fixes available
  //and Operator '<' cannot be applied to types 'boolean' and 'RegExp'.ts(2365)
  //Unterminated regular expression literal.ts(1161)
  //No quick fixes available
  return <AuthContext.Provider value={value}>{children}</AuthContext.Provider>
}

const useAuth = () => {
  const context = useContext(AuthContext);

  if (context === undefined)  {
    throw new Error("useAuth must be used within AuthContext");
  }

  return context;
}

export default useAuth;
```

In theroy , it should work,  then I can use as below:
[image]

But as you can see in first screenshot,  I cannot find a way to get rid of the redline.  And the app is not running because of the errors. Very strange.. it should work, right?
Can anyone point me out what's wrong with the setup ?
Thanks

Comment: [Please don't post code, exceptions, or results as images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question). They can't be copied (partly) for answering and their "text" won't appear in search engines. Images should only be used as a last resort.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your filename should end with `.tsx` instead of `.ts` when using JSX (html in js)